# pip can't run in virtualenv because of space in folder name

Tags: macos

I am trying to run pip in my virtual environment named venv. However when doing so I realised that my OS could not correctly interpret my path:

`/Users/Solal/Desktop/Some Name/scripts/some_name/some-name/venv/bin/pip`

`line 2: /Users/Solal/Desktop/Some: No such file or directory`

It seems there is an issue with the space in my folder "Some Name". Do you know what is happening and how to fix this without removing all the spaces I might have in my folders.

I have installed Python and pip with pyenv (which I installed with Homebrew). Virtualenv was installed with pip.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. There is no workaround other than removing the blank spaces or replacing the blank spaces with hyphens in the folder names.

Comment: Where is the bug from? pip, macos? Is it a known issue with a certain version? I never had this problem before today when I reinstall my python environmnent

Comment: This is a bug with some versions of pip. I faced it several times. Upgrading pip also may probably fix the issue.